# Why is Salesforce rounding up Value?

Tags: decimal, rounding

I have EnteredLoan **Amount (£) 999,999,999,999,999.99.**
However when i am doing query on Dev. Console it is returning me **1000000000000000.**

How do i avoid this?

Comment: Assuming you're using a field within the dev console, is the field set to have decimal points? Go into the object and click "edit" next to the field, from there you should check you've allowed 2 decimal points. I'd imagine it's rare a loan would have pennies associated with it, so it might be that it was built with no decimals in mind and it's rounding up from £0.99 to £1.

Comment: For context (an answer was deleted) - Currency fields configured with 0 decimal places **do not** round up. A quick test validates this. OP, could you please post a screenshot of 1. the field configuration and 2. the code you ran in execute anonymous?

Comment: Hi @BrianMansfield, I appreicate the feedback. Should've left it as a comment. Rather than leave it on, figured I'd remove it than risk spreading misinformation. Should've tested it! Another idea I had was that there may be some trigger in the background potentially rounding up on insert/update? Could do with a bit more information as Brian says. :)

Comment: does this problem also occur for smaller magnitude numbers - 99.99 rounds to 100 when queried in DC?